# Can azure/msal-node validate a token?

Tags: msal.js

I have been using passport with the passport-azure_ad extension to valid an azure ad jwt token in my server api. The passport-azure-ad package is now in maintenance mode and suggests that the code has been moved to azure/msal.

So does azure/msal-node provide a function to validate the azure ad jwt access token?

Answer (score 2):

I've also been struggling with this for a while.

According to [Sameera Gajjarapu](https://github.com/sameerag), a senior engineer in Azure Identity, passport-azure-ad is to be replaced by the [node-token-validation library](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/node-token-validation). He does not indicate however, any release date.

I suggest that you stick with passport-azure-ad until the new library is ready.

See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/pull/5034#issuecomment-1203450908.

To answer your question: You cannot validate access tokens with azure/msal-node.